# Add a UISegmentedController to navigation bar with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working with a `UITableView` that gets its data from an `NSFetchedResultsController`.  I would like to add a `UISegmentedControl` to my navigation bar that would toggle the table between displaying all of the records and only the records where `starred == YES`.

I have read some other SO posts indicating that one way to do this is to create a second `NSFetchedResultsController` that has an `NSPredicate` with `starred == YES`, but it seems awfully overkill to create a second `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Not according to the docs on NSFetchedResultsController. If you take a look at the documentation on the fetchRequests property, you'll see the following note:

> Important: You must not modify the
>   fetch request. For example, you must
>   not change its predicate or the sort
>   orderings.

Since the fetchRequest property is read-only, the only option is creating a new fetched results controller.

It might be possible to change the predicate and have things work, but it's generally a bad idea to do stuff that goes explicitly against things Apple says in the documentation, because it could break in a future release.

And, beware of premature optimization! Unless you've tested it out and found out that creating a whole new fetched results controller is a big performance drain, it's not worth trying to do something in a non-recommended way.

Here's how I set a new predicate on my fetched results controller. fetchedResultsController is a property of my view controller. predicate is a private ivar of the view controller.

I already had all of the code for creating the fetched results controller on demand, so to set the predicate it's just a matter of deleted the cached one.

```
- (void)setPredicate:(NSPredicate *)newPredicate {
    predicate = [newPredicate copy];

    // Make sure to delete the cache
    // (using the name from when you created the fetched results controller)
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];

    // Delete the old fetched results controller
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    // TODO: Handle error!
    // This will cause the fetched results controller to be created
    // with the new predicate
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This code if based on the boilerplate XCode generates when you start a project that uses Core Data.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[MyEntity entityName] inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: I would just create two separate FRC and assign them to different properties of controller. Then depending on which toggle is active, the table would use one or the other.

Comment: I like to have the generic approach, that you can change the predicate and everything else is handled in the background. It could even have multiple instances of the FRC and just swap them, based on the predicate....